# Does it make sense to say "with the exam passed"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases

I wonder if the sentence such makes sense?

> "I left the school with the exam (whatever this exam may be) passed"

The part I am not sure about is the phrase "with the exam passed".

I would like to point out the two facts "**I left the school**" and "**I passed the exam**", which are not necessarily connected. What would be a more idiomatic way to construct a sentence for that purpose?

Comment: Does "leave school" mean to drop out of school without degrees?

Answer (score 1):

It is not idiomatic.

There are lots of possible ways to phrase this.  If you just mean that two events occurred:

> I passed the exam and left school.

If the exam was the cause of you leaving

> I left school by passing the exam.

You can use a participle phrase

> Having passed the exam, I left school.

Or you can use the verb "graduate" which means "Leave school having passed all the required exams"

> I graduated.

Or, since the certificate (or diploma etc) implies passing the exam, you can say

> I left school with my diploma

Comment: Does "leave school" mean to drop out of school without degrees?

Comment: No, but if you have a new question, you might want to ask it as a question. rather than in a comment.